# Install plugin from another plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to use Redactor as a dependency for a plugin I'm writing.
I need it to be installed before I run my `Install.php` migration, because in the migration I'm creating a Redactor field.

Following this [question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33269/ns-prefix-plugingetinstance-returns-null-from-another-plugin-in-craft-3) I tried to listen to the AFTER_LOAD_PLUGINS Event:

```php
use craft\services\Plugins;
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\redactor\Plugin as Redactor;

class Plugin extends \craft\base\Plugin
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Event::on(Plugins::class, Plugins::EVENT_AFTER_LOAD_PLUGINS, function () {
            Redactor::getInstance()->install();
        });
    }
}
```

However `Redactor::getInstance()` still returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redactor::getInstance()`, will return the instance of the plugin, only if it is already installed.

Have you tried using `Craft::$app->getPlugins()->installPlugin('redactor');`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm